# Android remote server and mySql app isn't working. nullpointer exception

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, remote-server

I am trying to make a simple app that allows a user to Register with a username and password and then to log in with that username and password. I've created an Apache server and a MySql database however when I run the app on my phone and try to login with a username and password I've already added to the database manually it takes forever to attempt the login and then eventually crashes. I am using php scripts to parse the JSON data. Below is my java code as well as my logcat i do not see a point in posting the php scripts because I don't think they are the problem because if I try to log in from my computer browser with the php scripts it works fine. Please help me.

MainActivity

```
package com.example.mysqltest;

import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private EditText user, pass;
private Button mSubmit, mRegister;
private ImageView imageView;

 // Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

//php login script location:

//localhost :
//testing on your device
//put your local ip instead,  on windows, run CMD > ipconfig
//or in mac's terminal type ifconfig and look for the ip under en0 or en1
// private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:1234/webservice/login.php";

//testing on Emulator:
private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://10.0.0.106:80/webservice/login.php";

//testing from a real server:
//private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.yourdomain.com/webservice/login.php";

//JSON element ids from repsonse of php script:
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //setup input fields
    user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

    //setup buttons
    mSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
    mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.register);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


    //register listeners
    mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
    mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.login:
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
        break;
    case R.id.register:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Register.class);
            startActivity(i);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

     /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         // Check for success tag
        int success;
        String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                   LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                                    // save user data
                    SharedPreferences sp =  
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
                    Editor edit = sp.edit();
                    edit.putString("username", username);
                    edit.commit();

                Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReadComments.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }else{
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }
    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}

}
```

JSON Parser

```
package com.example.mysqltest;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}


public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // Construct the client and the HTTP request.
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        // Execute the POST request and store the response locally.
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        // Extract data from the response.
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        // Open an inputStream with the data content.
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        // Create a BufferedReader to parse through the inputStream.
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        // Declare a string builder to help with the parsing.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // Declare a string to store the JSON object data in string form.
        String line = null;

        // Build the string until null.
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        // Close the input stream.
        is.close();
        // Convert the string builder data to an actual string.
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // Try to parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // Return the JSON Object.
    return jObj;

}


// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

The register and login activities have the same problem so I dont see a point in adding the register activities. If you really need me to add the php scripts as well i will her is my

logcat

```
    09-08 11:45:02.765: I/Process(22450): Sending signal. PID: 22450 SIG: 9
09-08 11:45:47.730: D/libEGL(23410): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
09-08 11:45:47.735: D/libEGL(23410): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
09-08 11:45:47.740: D/libEGL(23410): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
09-08 11:45:47.745: E/(23410): Device driver API match
09-08 11:45:47.745: E/(23410): Device driver API version: 23
09-08 11:45:47.745: E/(23410): User space API version: 23 
09-08 11:45:47.745: E/(23410): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Wed Oct  9 21:05:57   
KST 2013 
09-08 11:45:47.830: D/OpenGLRenderer(23410): Enabling debug mode 0
09-08 11:45:47.895: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(23410): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
09-08 11:46:03.700: D/ProgressBar(23410): setProgress = 0
09-08 11:46:03.700: D/ProgressBar(23410): setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
09-08 11:46:03.700: D/ProgressBar(23410): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax =   
10000
09-08 11:46:03.755: D/dalvikvm(23410): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 282K, 14% free 9800K/11316K, paused 
23ms, total 29ms
09-08 11:46:03.755: I/dalvikvm-heap(23410): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.844MB for 1127536-byte 
allocation
09-08 11:46:03.775: D/dalvikvm(23410): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 14K, 13% free 10887K/12420K, paused  
21ms, total 21ms
09-08 11:46:03.815: D/request!(23410): starting
09-08 11:46:03.855: D/ProgressBar(23410): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
09-08 11:46:03.855: D/ProgressBar(23410): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
09-08 11:46:03.855: D/ProgressBar(23410): updateDrawableBounds: right = 96
09-08 11:46:03.855: D/ProgressBar(23410): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 96
09-08 11:48:22.855: D/dalvikvm(23410): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 440K, 14% free 10959K/12628K, paused 
30ms, total 30ms
09-08 11:49:13.445: W/System.err(23410): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: 
Connection to http://10.0.0.106:80 refused
09-08 11:49:13.450: W/System.err(23410):    at  

09-08 11:49:13.450: W/System.err(23410):    at  
org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
09-08 11:49:13.450: W/System.err(23410):    at  
org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
09-08 11:49:13.450: W/System.err(23410):    at 
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
09-08 11:49:13.455: W/System.err(23410):    at  
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
09-08 11:49:13.455: W/System.err(23410):    at 
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
09-08 11:49:13.455: W/System.err(23410):    at 
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
09-08 11:49:13.455: W/System.err(23410):    at 
com.example.mysqltest.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:110)
09-08 11:49:13.460: W/System.err(23410):    at 
com.example.mysqltest.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:133)
09-08 11:49:13.460: W/System.err(23410):    at 
com.example.mysqltest.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
09-08 11:49:13.460: W/System.err(23410):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
09-08 11:49:13.460: W/System.err(23410):    at 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
09-08 11:49:13.460: W/System.err(23410):    at   
android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
09-08 11:49:13.460: W/System.err(23410):    at    
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
09-08 11:49:13.460: W/System.err(23410):    at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
09-08 11:49:13.460: W/System.err(23410):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-08 11:49:13.465: W/System.err(23410): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect   
to /10.0.0.106 (port 80): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
09-08 11:49:13.470: W/System.err(23410):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
09-08 11:49:13.470: W/System.err(23410):    at   
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
09-08 11:49:13.470: W/System.err(23410):    at 
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
09-08 11:49:13.470: W/System.err(23410):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
09-08 11:49:13.475: W/System.err(23410):    at 
org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
09-08 11:49:13.475: W/System.err(23410):    at 
09-08 11:49:13.475: W/System.err(23410):    ... 15 more
09-08 11:49:13.475: W/System.err(23410): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed:    
ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
09-08 11:49:13.475: W/System.err(23410):    at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
09-08 11:49:13.475: W/System.err(23410):    at 
libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
09-08 11:49:13.480: W/System.err(23410):    at 
libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
09-08 11:49:13.480: W/System.err(23410):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
09-08 11:49:13.480: W/System.err(23410):    ... 20 more
09-08 11:49:13.480: E/Buffer Error(23410): Error converting result 
java.lang.NullPointerException:    
lock == null
09-08 11:49:13.480: E/JSON Parser(23410): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input 
at   
character 0 of 
09-08 11:49:13.480: W/dalvikvm(23410): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception  
(group=0x41c26700)
09-08 11:49:13.490: E/AndroidRuntime(23410): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-08 11:49:13.490: E/AndroidRuntime(23410): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while   
executing doInBackground()
09-08 11:49:13.490: E/AndroidRuntime(23410):    at 
android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
09-08 11:49:13.490: E/AndroidRuntime(23410):    at   
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
09-08 11:49:13.490: E/AndroidRuntime(23410):    at 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
09-08 11:49:13.490: E/AndroidRuntime(23410):    at 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
09-08 11:49:13.490: E/AndroidRuntime(23410):    at   
android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
09-08 11:49:13.490: E/AndroidRuntime(23410):    at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
09-08 11:49:13.490: E/AndroidRuntime(23410):    at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
09-08 11:49:13.490: E/AndroidRuntime(23410):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-08 11:49:13.490: E/AndroidRuntime(23410): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-08 11:49:13.490: E/AndroidRuntime(23410):    at 
com.example.mysqltest.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:137)
09-08 11:49:13.490: E/AndroidRuntime(23410):    at 
com.example.mysqltest.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
09-08 11:49:13.490: E/AndroidRuntime(23410):    at 
android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
09-08 11:49:13.490: E/AndroidRuntime(23410):    at   
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
09-08 11:49:13.490: E/AndroidRuntime(23410):    ... 4 more
09-08 11:49:22.300: I/Choreographer(23410): Skipped 508 frames!  The application may be doing too   
much work on its main thread.
09-08 11:49:22.500: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(23410): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
09-08 11:49:22.650: E/WindowManager(23410): Activity com.example.mysqltest.MainActivity has 
leaked  
window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{426fbb68 V.E..... R......D 0,0- 
684,192}   
that was originally added here
09-08 11:49:22.650: E/WindowManager(23410): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity 
com.example.mysqltest.MainActivity has leaked window    
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{426fbb68 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192}   
that   
was originally added here
09-08 11:49:22.650: E/WindowManager(23410):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>  
(ViewRootImpl.java:452)
09-08 11:49:22.650: E/WindowManager(23410):     at 
android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:258)
09-08 11:49:22.650: E/WindowManager(23410):     at   
android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:73)
09-08 11:49:22.650: E/WindowManager(23410):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:287)
09-08 11:49:22.650: E/WindowManager(23410):     at 
com.example.mysqltest.MainActivity$AttemptLogin.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:115)
09-08 11:49:22.650: E/WindowManager(23410):     at   
android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
09-08 11:49:22.650: E/WindowManager(23410):     at 
android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
09-08 11:49:22.650: E/WindowManager(23410):     at 
com.example.mysqltest.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:89)
09-08 11:49:22.650: E/WindowManager(23410):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
09-08 11:49:22.650: E/WindowManager(23410):     at    
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
09-08 11:49:22.650: E/WindowManager(23410):     at  
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
09-08 11:49:22.650: E/WindowManager(23410):     at    
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-08 11:49:22.650: E/WindowManager(23410):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
09-08 11:49:22.650: E/WindowManager(23410):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
09-08 11:49:22.650: E/WindowManager(23410):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native    
Method)
09-08 11:49:22.650: E/WindowManager(23410):     at   
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-08 11:49:22.650: E/WindowManager(23410):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
09-08 11:49:22.650: E/WindowManager(23410):     at     
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
09-08 11:49:22.650: E/WindowManager(23410):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: URL you are trying to connect is not available or IP of your local server got changed etc try browsing same url from browser

Comment: @praveen Thanks a lot. So would you know how I can add something to stop the app from crashing when that happens, instead just say like "error with login" because when the phone has not connection then the app will crash instead of saying like: "no internet connection"

Comment: @praveen I checked my IP and tried the url on my computers browser and it works, still not working on the phone though... i dont understand why!

Comment: try to catch exception whatever you are getting and return some value with which you can recognize

Comment: how are saying in browser it is working, it is returning expected Json when you are trying same URL from browser

Comment: @praveen Yes, with the exact same URL

Comment: can you post Url response from browser?

Comment: @praveen It's just his josn respnse: {"success":1,"message":"Login successful!"}

Comment: are you using **<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />**